# Consolidate "Word-choice" and "Usage" tags

Tags: discussion, tags

Should these tags be consolidated, or are they two separate entities?

Answer (score 3):

I think they are two separate entities. You can certainly ask a usage question about a single word, phrase, particle, etc.

It just so happens that so far in these early days we are getting lots of questions which on the English L&U site would be tagged `differences` that actually do deal with the different usages of two or more competing constructions.

Comment: i agree with your statement about when asked for a single word.  However, what i think will happen is that there are going to be alot of posts like the わけ and はず post where they will end up with both tags.  

my recommendation would be to consolidate into just the one Usage tags as it covers both instances.

I also think "Differences" is a horrible tag-name, but that's just me.

Comment: Yeah I feel the "differences" tag is ugly but on the other (pragmatic) hand it does have a very clear and obvious use. It's not technical or Japanese-ish or linguistic. But it's very user-friendly and hard to get wrong for a Q&A site.